# Install new environment (GNOME/General) over existing (Minimal) from USB

Tags: desktop-environment, scientific-linux

I tried installing Scientific Linux 7.5 and didn't know which environment to go for. It recommended going with Minimal Install and `yum` installing necessary packages later. Problem is, I don't think it installed `wireless-tools`. So `ifconfig`, `iw`, etc. don't work, so no `yum` for me.

Is it possible to somehow install a new environment or packages from the bootable USB I used?

Comment: As this sounds like a fresh install it is almost certainly faster to run the installer again, reinstall, and install gnome. Your other option would be do download any  packages you need for internet connection on another system and transfer and install, and then configure your network.

Comment: Have you tried using the `ip addr` command? You can use `ip` to configure the network.

Answer (score 0):

If this system has a wired connection, do the following:

> $ ip a

note the LAN interface; then

> dhclient interface

If 'dhclient' is not present, you can try dhcpcd as:

> dhcpcd interface

This should get you on the network (provided DHCP server is running on your network).

dhclient and dhcpcd are DHCP clients which discovers and requests IP addresses from DHCP server (if any, on your network)

As an example, on my Ubuntu 16.04 sandbox, I have two interfaces, 'lo' and 'enp0s3'. Latter is the LAN connection and I'd do the following in order to get the IP address:

> dhclient enp0s3